# PHP file download are blocked by Chrome due to insecure connection (mixed-content)

Tags: php, google-chrome, https, http-headers, mixed-content

I have a few projects where file downloads don't works anymore. It seems due to a recent Chrome policy change.

Downloads tries fails with this error in the console :

```
Mixed Content: The site at 'https://example.com/' was loaded over a secure connection, but the file at 'https://example.com/logs_view.php?export=true' was redirected through an insecure connection. This file should be served over HTTPS. This download has been blocked. See https://blog.chromium.org/2020/02/protecting-users-from-insecure.html for more details.
```

My files are served thru PHP :

```
header("Content-Type: application/xls");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename.".xls");  
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");
echo utf8_decode($export);
```

It seems this method don't send the file with HTTPS headers... Any idea on how to fix this ?

You can find below the headers of the server response header :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 19 Jan 2021 11:33:14 GMT
Server: Apache
Expires: 0
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=base_changelog_2021-01-19_12-33-14.xls
Content-Length: 899
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=92
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/xls
```

Thanks a lot for your support.

Ben

Comment: any luck with this issue? I'm facing the same\

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in Your code.
When You make redirect to the url which returns file You are trying to do it from http while you are on https secure connection. Probably You have link with wrong protocol.

Answer (score -2):

I find a way to force chrome to "upgrade" the download.

I added to my .htaccess this tweak, and it did the job!!!

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;"
</IfModule>
```